# Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null with ngif

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, istanbul

I am doing some unit tests.

So I have this function:

```
selectCluster(event: MouseEvent, feature: any) {
    event.stopPropagation(); 
    this.selectedCluster = {geometry: feature.geometry, properties: feature.properties};
  }
```

and tempplate:

```
 <mgl-popup *ngIf="selectedCluster" [feature]="selectedCluster">
      
    </mgl-popup>
```

and I have the test like this:

```
  fit('Should set selectedCluster when clicked', async(() => {    

    spyOn(component, 'selectCluster').and.callThrough();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.marker-cluster')).nativeElement.click();
    tick();

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(component.selectCluster).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  }));
```

But I still get this error:

```
Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null
```

So what I have to change?

Thank you

This also use the function:

```
 <ng-template mglClusterPoint let-feature>
        <div class="marker-cluster" (click)="selectCluster($event, feature)">
          <fa-icon [icon]="faVideo" [styles]="{'stroke': 'black', 'color': 'black'}" size="lg" class="pr-2"></fa-icon>
          <fa-icon [icon]="faWifi" [styles]="{'stroke': 'black', 'color': 'black'}" size="lg" class="pr-2"></fa-icon>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.marker-cluster` is not on the page when you attempt to click it, I don't see your full html but I will assume it is related to `*ngIf="selectedCluster"` being true.

```
 fit('Should set selectedCluster when clicked', async(() => {    
    // spy on and calling through doesn't actually call the function
    // it makes it so we can determine if the function was called
    // and everytime the function was called, call the actual function
    // and not a null function
    spyOn(component, 'selectCluster').and.callThrough();
    // calling the function will should make selectedCluster true
    component.selectCluster({ stopPropagation: () => null } as MouseEvent, {}); // send your own inputs
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.marker-cluster')).nativeElement.click();

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(component.selectCluster).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  }));
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. I added some more html. But in this case I still get the same error

Comment: Yes, it is related to state = true

Comment: Ok, you have to understand why `marker-cluster` is null at that point in time. Maybe you're not setting up everything correctly for it to be painted?

Comment: Yes, I understand that I think. Because you are right it is null when the HML is loaded. Because it is from map. Mapbox

Comment: Ok, before calling the first `detectChanges`, make sure it is truthy.